# How can a magnetic field exert a torque that causes a disc to rotate?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, torque, electromagnetic-induction, angular-velocity

I'm confused about the premise of this homework problem:

> A thin, non-conducting horizontal disc lies in the $x$-$y$ plane.  The disc has a mass $m$ and a total charge $q$ distributed uniformly over its surface. 
>    The disc can freely rotate about its axis.
> $\hspace{175px}$[image]
> The disc is initially stationary.  Then, at time $t=0 ,$ a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ directed in the direction of the $z$-axis (so perpendicular to the disc's plane) is switched on.
>
> **Problem:**  Find the disc's angular velocity $\omega \left( t \right)$ as function of time, assuming that $\mathrm{B}=kt ,$ where $t$ is time.

This problem implies that the magnetic field, $\vec{B} ,$ causes a torque, making the disc rotate.  However, I don't understand how the magnetic field would cause the disc to rotate at all.

I have studied electromagnetic induction, and I know that an electromotive force (emf) will be generated due to the change in magnetic flux.  But, how will this emf help this disc to rotate?

**Question:**  How does the magnetic field perpendicular to the disc cause it to rotate?

Comment: Please give me suggestion what should I do to improve my question. Any specific reason to down vote this question?

Comment: This looks very much like a "how do I solve this problem" question which is considered off-topic here, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @Kyle But, I am only asking about which torque operates and how? Not asking people to solve the  numerical for me. Just about the torque and its working.

Comment: If that is your interest, I think you need to edit the question to remove the "this is my homework, what do I do next" aspect and focus on the conceptual question you want to ask.

Comment: @Kyle Please see if now it is okay to ask?

Comment: Welcome to SE.Physics!  I edited your question a bit to try to make it clearer.  Please feel free to fix anything that may be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, electromagnetic induction is about the existence of an electric field with non-conservative circulation.

This electric field can generate a current in a closed circuit, that is to say to make charges turn !

In your case, you must first look for the **electric field** associated with the variable magnetic field and then look at how this electric field acts on the charged disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your knowledge of e-m induction will have enabled you to find the emf around a circle of radius *r* on the disc. That means you know know much work per coulomb would be done on a test charge taken around that circle. But you know what *work* means, so you can calculate the force per unit charge on your test charge. What do we call this?